# How can I implement another action after the animation has ended? - Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

***Can anyone help?***
=====================================================
**I tried like this:**

```
Animation zoom, zoom_out;


zoomAnimation();
```

```
private void zoomAnimation() {
        zoom= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fast_zoomin);
        avatar.startAnimation(zoom);
 
        //question
        if (zoom.hasEnded()){
            zoomoutAnimation();
        }
        //question

    }

    private void zoomoutAnimation() {
        zoom_out= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fast_zoomout);
        avatar.startAnimation(zoom_out);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it so that when the animation started, exactly as many seconds elapsed as the animation lasted, after that another action will begin (C help of the Handler method).

```
private void zoomAnimation() {
        zoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fast_zoomin);
        zoom_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fast_zoomout);
        avatar.startAnimation(zoom);

        if (!zoom.hasStarted()){
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    avatar.startAnimation(zoom_out);
                }
            }, 1500); //seconds after which another action will start when
                      //condition that the first one started
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly.
But I think that you need just to add a module. When the animation ends, the object still exist, so you can connect an action with an intent-filter.
Hope to be of help